# Will this MySQL tables structure help me on performance and scalability?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `behaviour` with 5 million rows (660 mb) that increases every day. This table holds some behavioural data and two of the columns in this table are:

```
page_title ------- url
page 1 ---- page1.html
page 1 ---- page1.html
page 1 ---- page1.html
page 1 ---- page1.html
page 2 ---- page2.html
page 2 ---- page2.html
page 1 ---- page1.html
page 3 ---- page3.html
page 3 ---- page3.html
page 3 ---- page3.html
```

I have `url` as index since I perform a lot of SELECT queries.
The distinct count of `page_title` (and `url`) is 2700.

The `page_title` is TEXT with a lot of chars, and the main reason for the disk space.

Do you suggest me to build another table, let's say `all_pages` that will have the distinct result of the 2 columns found on `behaviour`, remove the `page_title` column from `behaviour` and to retrieve the `page_title` by making `join` between the two tables?

Will this help me on the performance and future scalability?

Answer (score 0):

all you really need to do to link the 2 tables will be a related records field that links the record to the record owner (related record from another table) but if you are only talking about a table with a few columns I don't know that this will help anything. What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

What about this design:

```
pages.id page_title url
-------- ---------- ----------
1        page 1 ... page1.html
2        page 2 ... page2.html 
3        page 3 ... page3.html

stats.id page_id created             ip         ...
-------- ------- ------------------- ---------- ---
1        1       2017-01-01 00:00:00 1234567890 ...
2        1       ...                 ...        ...
```